# Enumerating Groups using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() returns old set of groups

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, credentials

I have a user that when I attempt to enumerate her groups using either
`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups` on user's computer
or `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups` on the IIS server, I get a list of their old groups, not their new.

I have checked the DC that they authenticate to and the ASP.NET page is running inside a SharePoint instance so the LogonUserIdentity most like is being provided from there Kerberos ticket.

Should I be looking up the groups directly from the AD instead of relying on the WindowsIdentity or LogonUserIdentity?

Comment: So to complete the loop.  The token for the group never refreshed until she was added back to the old group and the removed again.  Additionally she was removed from the new group and added back to the group.  This was sufficient to cause something to be reset and force the groups to be represented properly in LoginUserIdentity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `WindowsIdentity` or `LogonUserIdentity`, it's going to retrieve the group information from the authorization data stored in the Kerberos ticket-granting ticket (TGT).

It's powerful and useful because once you are authenticated and you get the Kerberos TGT, you don't need to query Active Directory again to get all the group information.  Actually, group enumeration is pretty expensive and complicated.  Therefore, the Kerberos ticket approach is preferred and this approach is being used when you access any Windows resources.

However, this also means that after you add your user account to a group, `WindowsIdentity` or `LogonUserIdentity` approach won't know the newly added groups.  You have to purge your Kerberos ticket and get it again.  You can logoff and then logon or you can lock your screen and type in the password to unlock your screen.

If for some reasons, you still want to do the group enumeration yourself, I recommend you to use [UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx) in .NET 3.5.  It returns all the security groups a user belongs to.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but is there any documentation that shows that logging off and back on again will force WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups to be updated? I want to ensure that after a user logs off and back on that the Groups are updated every time - Can't find anything on MSDN so far